# Hiding middle view first in coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-animation, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a layout as follows

- Layout1
- Layout2
- ScrollView

When scrolling I need Layout2 disappear first then Layout1. For example look at the following gif middle view disappear first then top view disappear. I suspect I need some custom behavior code but don't know where to start.

[image]

Here's my current xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.chamoda.coordinatelayoutdemo.ScrollingActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll" >

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.chamoda.coordinatelayoutdemo.ScrollingActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:text="@string/large_text" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

How do I archive that animation using coordinate layout?

Comment: Met with the same problem. Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `Toolbar` to make it.
Please see this great tutorial for more information:

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en

Comment: Thanks, but I could not find anything helpful to my exact use case. Every use case I found in CollapsingToolbarLayout moves top layout first. May be I'm missing something?